# Call an app from a bash script Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

I have an app in a specific installed  on my Ubuntu machine which is installed in `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp` and when I try using `myfn` in my bash script `mybashscript.sh` it gives an error saying that the `myfn` command is not found but if I call `myfn` from a normal terminal window it works fine since it's found in the `~/.bashrc` file, so I wonder how I can call `myfn` from my bash script `mybashscript.sh`?

Here is `mybashscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

alias brc='source ~/.bashrc'

source /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
#exec bash
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
echo $PATH
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
```

This is the output when I run `./mybashscript.sh`:

```
bash: /bin/realbin/myapp: No such file or directory
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: 3: /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: /bin/realbin/myapp: not found
```

Comment: call it by its full path?

Comment: @DavidDai I'm already calling the file by the full path as shown in the question but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `source` to load the function into the script:

```
source /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
```

To make the function globally available to all sub-shells (e.g. scripts) , use `export`. In your case this command would follow the function definition in `~/.bashrc`.

```
export -f myfn
```

Edit: 
You are having an issue which is reported here:

```
bash: /bin/realbin/myapp: No such file or directory
```

This is because the file `/bin/realbin/myapp` does not exist.

Comment: I've updated the question with my script and output, could you please check?

Comment: Instead of the last line, don't you just need `myfn`?  which calls the function defined in the myapp file.

Comment: I want to run myapp which then I passes some arguments to it. But when I call it gives some errors saying not found as shown in the question, but if I run it in terminal normally like this `myapp` it will work fine, not sure how I can make it also work from `mybashscript.sh`

Comment: see my edit....

Comment: But I don't know why `/bin/realbin/myapp` doesn't exist, I mean myapp is located in `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin` not `/bin/realbin/`

Comment: perhaps show your script?

Comment: It's in my question

Comment: I meant the myapp script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98777/discussion-between-tak-and-suspectus).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `source` the file containing the function?

**i.e.** if I add bash functions in my `.bashrc` file (where I like them to be); I need to `source` the containing file, `.bashrc` in this case, in order to have them available globally.

*NB:* `source` is executed at boot, so I need to *manually* call it only if I edit functions, in order to *update* the source(code).

Comment: I've updated the question with my script and output, could you please check?

Comment: Are those *links*? Please, list directories content...